# How to access Raised Button in flutter from another function to change that button border or background color?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

```
Expanded(
  child: RaisedButton(

    splashColor: Colors.red,
    elevation: 1.0,
    onPressed: (){
     _buttonTag = ButtonPressed(2);
     setState(() {

       _visible = false;
     });
      Navigator.of(context).push(_ProfileToStory());
      print('pressed2');},
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Icon(
        Icons.favorite
    ),


  ),
)
```

I am new to Flutter.

We used to have an outlet for button globally so that we can access that button from anywhere in the class. How we can do that in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I figured out by taking a bool **_button1Pressed** and changing its value in **setSate** method. Is this right approach?

```
     class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
       @override
      _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
       }

 class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
      bool _visible = true;
      bool _button1Pressed = true;

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Madelyn Johnson'),
        centerTitle: true,
         backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
         ),

        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 1.0,
                color: _button1Pressed ? Colors.pinkAccent : Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _visible = true;
                    _button1Pressed = true;
                  });
                  print('pressed1');
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                elevation: 1.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _visible = false;
                    _button1Pressed = false;
                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).push(_ProfileToStory());
                  print('pressed2');
                },
                color: _button1Pressed ? Colors.white : Colors.pinkAccent,
                child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to access button. Instead access the variable inside the Raised button by declaring it yourself. If your Raised button is in a StatefulWidget class. You can simply change the state of the function with setState().

And instead of using row string, u can declear a variable in place of title or color and change it with setState() function from another function.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class Test extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TestState createState() => _TestState();
    }

    class _TestState extends State<Test> {
      String btnTitle = "Some Text";

      void myFunction(){
        setState(() {
          btnTitle = "Changed Title";
        });
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Experiment"),
          ),

          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text(btnTitle),
                onPressed: (){

                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Change Title"),
                onPressed: (){
                  myFunction();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),

        );
      }
    }
```

Here, I am changing the title of one RaisedButton from another.

Comment: thanks but my motive is not only title. My query is. generic like in native we had tag number for every button what if I have to change border color or highlight the button. so how am going to access that specific button in. set state method. ?

Comment: As I said, we do not access the button. we simply acess the variables inside. U can change every single state, it might be color / border / margin / padding / opacity / elevation /  or even replace a child widget using setState

Comment: Say there is a way and u declared RaisedButton mybutton = RaisedButton(child:text("hello")); And lets say mybutton.child gives u access to child element of RaisedButton. If you could change this way, flutter would not know during run time that something has changed. So u must use setState to change and create variables in place of constant properties

Comment: it worked I created a bool and put a check on color property and everytime I was  clicking the button Changed the value of bool.

Comment: see? you don't need tags or access to instance. You just need a variable and setState